# Find the first differing character between two Strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have two strings.

```
str_a = "the_quick_brown_fox"
str_b = "the_quick_red_fox"
```

I want to find the first index at which the two strings differ (i.e. `str_a[i] != str_b[i]`).

I know I could solve this with something like the following:

```
def diff_char_index(str_a, str_b)
  arr_a, arr_b = str_a.split(""), str_b.split("")
  return -1 unless valid_string?(str_a) && valid_string?(str_b)
  arr_a.each_index do |i|
    return i unless arr_a[i] == arr_b[i]
  end
end

def valid_string?(str)
  return false unless str.is_a?(String)
  return false unless str.size > 0
  true
end

diff_char_index(str_a, str_b) # => 10
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
str_a.each_char.with_index
  .find_index {|char, idx| char != str_b[idx] } || str_a.size
```

**Edit:** It works: http://ideone.com/Ttwu1x
**Edit 2:** My original code returned `nil` if `str_a` was shorter than `str_b`. I've updated it to work correctly (it will return `str_a.size`, so if e.g. the last index in `str_a` is 3, it will return 4).

Here's another method that may strike some as slightly simpler:

```
(0...str_a.size).find {|i| str_a[i] != str_b[i] } || str_a.size
```

http://ideone.com/275cEU

Comment: I'd prefer `str_a.each_char.with_index`, as it doesn't create an intermediate array. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: Good catch, @Amadan. I always forget about `each_char`.

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 0
i += 1 while str_a[i] and str_a[i] == str_b[i]
i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str_a = "the_quick_brown_dog"
str_b = "the_quick_red_dog"

(0..(1.0)/0).find { |i| (str_a[i] != str_b[i]) || str_a[i].nil? }
  #=> 10

str_a = "the_quick_brown_dog"
str_b = "the_quick_brown_dog"

(0..(1.0)/0).find { |i| (str_a[i] != str_b[i]) || str_a[i].nil? }
  #=> 19
str_a.size
  #=> 19
```

Comment: Why not just write `Float::INFINITY` instead of `(1.0)/0`?

Comment: @Jordan, I shouldn't be so flippant. I agree that `Float::INFINITY` is better. In fact, I originally wrote that, but then decided to change it for the benefit of readers unfamiliar with `(1.0)/0`.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a binary search to find the index where a slice of `str_a` no longer occurs at the beginning of `str_b`:

```
(0..str_a.length).bsearch { |i| str_b.rindex(str_a[0..i]) != 0 }
```